# BDD tests should be written by Developers OR Testers?

Tags: selenium, bdd

In our team the Developers are arguing they should not be writing the BDD tests since BDD tests are automation tests and QA team should be writing it.

Is that how everyone else out there does it? Or do you have Developers writing BDD tests?

By the way...we use SCRUM methodology on our team.
Regards

Comment: Is there a reason this has been put on hold? I am looking for opinions whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your team and which development methodology you using.

In SCRUM, developers should write tests and QA (which strictly speaking must not exist as part of the development team) may perform infrequent manual tests, that cannot be automated (such as usability tests, information perception, colour choice). In this sense, QA becomes a 3-rd party service, that does not participate in everyday development. A team may use occasionally this service to get specialised feedback.

From the [scrum guide](https://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guide) (with my emphasis)

> Scrum recognizes **no sub-teams** in the Development Team, regardless of
>   particular domains  that need to be addressed like testing or business
>   analysis; there are no exceptions to this  rule; [...]

In (iterative) waterfall, QA and customers, can write BDD and acceptance tests. They can do this in plain English, leaving programmatic implementation of the tests to the developers.

The fact that the tests are automated doesn't mean that developers should delegate writing tests to QA.

Comment: We use SCRUM methodology and i am struggling to explain to developers that all pro developers using BDD write the test themselves.

Comment: Looks like developers lack training in the methodology. I would advice to perform formal/informal training.

Answer (score 1):

BDD - behaviour driven development is method by which developer writes automated test cases.  Anyone who is writing code can write this.  Suppose any team is following TDD then BDD is not required as the case may be.  BDD is basically for developers who is developing some software based on behavior by using some tools like specflow.

I hope this will help.